# Printing to a file in windows98

Tags: windows-98

I have an old medical equipment, with a software which works only with windows98, no update available, my problem is i can't find a printer compatible with win98, also the software prints only on parallel port (LPT),

So now am looking for some trick to print into a file (image, pdf, ...) using a virtual printer or anything, so any help or idea will be appreaciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp). CutePDF Writer installs itself as a "printer subsystem".

You can check this [CutePDF FAQ](http://www.cutepdf.com/Support/faq.asp#Writer) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

PDF995 would work great for tyour situation since it installs a printerd and anything sent to it is automatically converted to a PDF.

Comment: sorry but that don't install on win98

Comment: Yes it does, From web site: We support Windows 8; Windows 7; Vista; XP; Citrix/Terminal Server; configuration as a shared network printer; Server 2003, 2008 and 2012; and Windows 95, 98, NT 4.0, 2000 and ME. We support Windows 32 bit and 64 bit operating systems.   Don;t forget to vote.

Comment: i've tried it on win98 it starts two windows shows (self extractor), then nothing happens (WIN98 SE) !!!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) (which includes GhostPDF) for several years.  Setup is *potentially* easy.